# ubuntu libre office need different font list

Tags: ubuntu, fonts, libreoffice

Just installed new machine with ubuntu 14.04.  The font list showing in Libre office has none of the fonts I usually use, and none of the fonts I need,  although it is well equipped with fonts for various languages I never heard of.  I looked around for fonts and found lots and lots of folders containing fonts.  But I have no idea which folder Libre office might be accessing for its font list.  If it is one folder, it is not any that I have found.

Can anyone tell me which folder to look at, or whether I can direct Libre Office to the font folder of my choice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

LibreOffice will read all installed fonts in `/usr/share/fonts/`, which is where fonts packages are installed by the Software Center.

Additionally, if you copy/download individual fonts, you can put them in your `/home/your-user-name/.fonts/` folder, which will make them available only to the current user. LibreOffice will find those automatically, too.

If `/home/your-user-name/.fonts/` does not exist, you can create it from the file explorer or from the terminal:

```
mkdir .fonts
```

You must be in `/home/your-user-name/` directory, when you execute this command.

or do this:

```
mkdir /home/your-user-name/.fonts
```

And if you don't know how to check whether or not `.fonts` directory exits, execute the following command from the terminal, it will show you all the hidden directories:

```
ls -a
```

Comment: Thank you, that helps.  I have 4 folders in usr/share/fonts.  Would it be possible for me to eliminate some of the fonts that Libre office is displaying by deleting or moving these folders?  For example, I will never use Droid Sans Ethiopic -- I have about 30 of this kind of thing cluttering up my list.

Comment: To remove the fonts you should install the graphical interface for fonts manager. To install this run this command in the terminal: `sudo apt-get install font-manager`. To run the font-manager, run this command: `font-manager`. It will let you see all the fonts installed on your system and will let you disable them. Please mark my answer as accpeted if it helped you out.

Comment: Or if you want to completely remove the unwanted fonts, you can remove them with root privileges as you said from `/usr/share/fonts`. The command for that would be `sudo rm -r /usr/share/fonts/name-of-the-directory-you-want-to-delete`.

Comment: HI chipChoc, yes I installed font-manager and it helped me get rid of all the junk.  I was also able to install the fonts I actually want.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: Thanks for reminding me.  BTW, I was able to install the font manager from the Ubuntu software center, so I didn't have to go through the terminal.  The home/betty/.fonts came into existence when I double clicked on an existing backed up font and requested an install.  I installed my other five or six needed fonts that way from back up or from a download.

Answer (score 1):

just copy the font file (.ttf; .otf) to /usr/share/fonts and exec #fc-cache -fv